# Separando páginas por categorias (incluindo permalinks)

Tags: wordpress

Estou trabalhando num projeto em que é necessário que exista uma separação por tipos de páginas. Funciona assim:

Ao acessar o website, o visitante deve escolher se é **Empresa** ou **Candidato**, e eu gostaria que a URL separasse empresa de candidato, como:

nomedosite.com/empresa/
nomedosite.com/candidato/

Existem várias páginas diferentes no grupo empresa e também várias páginas diferentes no grupo candidato. Preciso que a URL final seja: http://nomedosite.com/candidato/contato, por exemplo.

Dentro do site também existem diversas postagens no blog da empresa e no blog do candidato, e necessito que fiquem assim, por exemplo:

http://nomedosite.com/candidato/blog/postagem-do-blog-candidato.

Já pesquisei muito mas não encontrei nada que me ajudasse a separar as páginas... Somente os posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar as páginas da URL que vem antes da página final como Página mãe. vlw

Comment: Deu certo cara!!